# RestTemplate: how to deal with metadata

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I have to consume a REST webservice which has the following syntax for all requests:

```
{
  message: "OK",
  success: true,
  results: 1,
  data: {
    name: "Berlin",
    lat: 52.2,
    lon: 13.25,
    id: 1701
  },
  (...)
}
```

When I try to deserialize using:

```
City source = getRestTemplate().getForObject("http://myws.com/cities/{cityId}", City.class, "1701");
```

The default HttpMessageConverter tries to look for attributes named message, success, results in the City bean, and since it cannot find them, it's throwing an Exception.

I wonder if there's any way to take advantage of the default HttpMessageConverter but somehow tell it to interpret message, success and results differently, or do I have to create my own HttpMessageConverter altogether?

Comment: Please clarify the `(...)` in the response. The data format seems to imply (`results: 1`) that you might get a whole collection of data elements...

Comment: Yes, that is the syntax. If it's only one then data will hold one element, if results is bigger than one, then it's a collection of elements.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and the way around it is to create a wrapper object that contains the meta data fields.  This method turned out to be quite useful and made it incredibly easy to get at the data.

In your case, the core model is obviously the city but then the wrapper object would be something like this

```
class CityWrapper{
   String message;
   String success;
   Integer results;

   @JsonProperty("data")
   City city;
}
```

When I tackled it I had a list of data coming back and that worked fine with

```
@JsonProperty("data")
List<City> cities;
```

Comment: Exactly. Make the class model match the serialized structure.